# Android VideoView Error 1,0

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-videoview

I have an application thats main goal is to play a specific video file.

it plays the video correctly sometimes. But other times it gives me this error:

```
03-21 14:52:36.181: I/AwesomePlayer(119): 
setDataSource_l('/data/data/my.package.name/files/MyMovie.mp4')
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612): Unable to open content: /data/data/my.package.name/files/MyMovie.mp4
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The surface has been released
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setVideoSurface(Native Method)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDisplay(MediaPlayer.java:633)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:222)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:49)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:465)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:533)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1617)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 14:52:36.196: D/VideoView(26612): Error: 1,0
```

I am using the prepared listener to call start like this:

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        mVideoView.start();

    }
});
```

And I set the data source with this:

```
file = new File(this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + VIDEO_FILE_NAME);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I know for certain that the file does exist and is the proper format.

My application has the ability to be launched from an alarm trigger. It seems to only be a problem when the trigger fires and launches my app while the devices screen is turned off(my app will turn the screen on with a wake lock). If I manually launch the app, or the trigger happens with the screen on the video plays fine. This error is also only occuring on the Galaxy Nexus. I can run the exact same code on a Nexus S(as well as a long list of others) and it starts fine every time.

Does anyone know of anything specific to the Galaxy Nexus or ICS that could cause this behavior? And are there any suggestions for what I could try to fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UThis is connected to your SurfaceView.
Make sure you don't touch the SurfaceView after you have called prepare on you MediaPlayer and that it is visible. In your case where you try to wake up the screen make sure that everything happens in the correct order. So preparing the MediaPlayer for playback is the very last thing which your app should do. It could be that the prepare/playback is initiated prior to the app being fully awake, causing the app to attempt to manipulate the  SurfaceView.

The follow code example illustrates how to trigger that kind of exception:

```
   private void setupVideo(String file){
      ...
      mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
      mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder(); // DON'T TOUCH BEHIND THIS POINT
      mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
      mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);
      mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
      mMediaPlayer.prepare();
   }
   @Override
   public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
      mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // THIS WILL CAUSE THE ERROR
      mp.start();
   }
```

Comment: most of this should be getting abstracted away by the VideoView though shouldn't it? The only calls I have to make are .prepare(), and then .start(). And start gets called by the listener, same as you have it set up. So prepare() is the only one being called from my Activities scope.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with an ICS no name tablet.

SurfaceHolder isn't created when setDisplay method is called, which cause:

```
03-21 14:52:36.196: W/VideoView(26612): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The surface has been released
```

To fix it, I use:

```
private void setupVideo(String file){
    ...
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mHolder=mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    mHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mHolder=holder;
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);
            ...
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { ... }
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { ... }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
    ...
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got around this issue with the below implementation.

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    Log.v("MediaVideo", "onPause");
    super.onPause();
    this.mVideoView.pause();
    this.mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    Log.v("MediaVideo", "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    Log.v("MediaVideo", "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    this.mVideoView.resume();
}
```

Override the OnPause and call mVideoView.pause() and the set visibility to GONE.
This way I could resolve the "Activity has leaked window" log error issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Galaxy Nexus by any chance rooted and running the Keyboard Manager app?
I saw the exact same stack trace as you when testing my app out and kept noticing the following line in my logcat dumps:

```
06-26 08:42:49.511 I/ActivityManager(  218): START {flg=0x10050000 cmp=com.ne0fhykLabs.android.utility.km/.TransitionDialog} from pid 11150
```

This is the Keyboard Manager app kicking in as soon as the screen orientation changed.

As soon as I disabled the Keyboard Manager service, everything started working again with my video.

As far as I can tell, they were both using the same SurfaceHolder, and when Keyboard Manager was done with it, it was released, causing that exception when the VideoView tried to use it.

In order to get around this, you could try what is mentioned [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://dingran.iteye.com/blog/1442502&prev=/search?q=IllegalArgumentException%2b%2522The%2bsurface%2bhas%2bbeen%2breleased%2522&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1600&bih=753&prmd=imvns&sa=X&ei=pyHrT8DGLZTW2wW-kYnYAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CGYQ7gEwAw) (the site is in Chinese, but the link is translated). I haven't tried it yet, but hopefully it will work since it's using its own dedicated SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `onpause` and `onresume` callbacks seemed to fix it for me and it's ONLY for the NEXUS Galaxy that has this problem.