# Videoview not working. Displaying black screen

Tags: android, android-videoview, daydream

I'm trying to create a `DayDream` service which should play several videos.
I manage to make the `DayDream` service appear but the video doesn't play....only a black screen appears.
No errors or exceptions.

```
package com.android.DayVideoDream;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.service.dreams.DreamService;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class DVDmain extends DreamService implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Displays a video file.
        VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

        String uriPath = "android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"
                + R.raw.filme3_h264;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video is playing",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

Can't find the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812067/android-videoview-error-1-0